Detecting the erroneous deletion of a raw pointer
I'm well aware that throwing exceptions from destructors is almost universally regarded as a Bad Idea.
But I've been dealing with a case where I have a class that is only ever intended to be held within a std::unique_ptr, so that each object's lifetime is managed by the unique pointer. However, there are occasions when I have to pass such an object's raw pointer to legacy code, or even to third-party libraries.
If the temporary owner of that raw pointer attempts to delete the object, I want to know about it straight away. Otherwise, when the std::unique_ptr goes out of scope, it will try to delete the object a second time and cause a crash - but by the time that happens, it will be very difficult to work out where the first deletion (via the raw pointer) took place. I'd far prefer for the crash to take place at the first deletion, so I can easily locate the problem and fix the code there.
Here's the best solution I've been able to think of so far:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class managedLifetime
{
public:
    managedLifetime() { }
    
    virtual ~managedLifetime()
    {
        throw()
    }
};

class managedLifetimeCustomDeleter
{
public:
    // Delete the object, safely catching the exception 
    void operator()(managedLifetime * ml) const
    {
        try
        {
            delete ml;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
};

function hazard(managedLifetime * object)
{
    // I want this to crash
    delete object;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<managedLifetime, managedLifetimeCustomDeleter> obj( new managedLifetime(); )
    
    hazard(obj.get());

    std::cout << "I want the application to crash before I get to here" << std::endl;
}

The code will crash anyway after the text is outputted, but I want the crash to occur before then, so I have a chance of identifying it.
Is this a genuine case of where throwing from a destructor can be excused? Or is there a simpler and safer way of achieving the same objective?

Instead of throwing, your could call std::abort and investigate the corefile.

Pass opaque pointers or tokens, rather than the raw pointer.  The legacy code might not be using the proper delete, or delete[] or free or inapplicable (such as for an automatic storage local variable or a static storage static variable) anyway.

What you say sounds... strange. To invoke the destructor of your type, that legacy code or third-party libraries would need to see the definition of that type which only makes sense for template libraries.

Since C++11 destructor can't throw exceptions - this will lead to abort. They are implicitly declared as noexcept.

Instead inventing some crazy code, start using existing tooling. Looks like you should start using valgrind or better address sanitzers (delivered by compilers), this way you will find memory issues without problems and writing strange code.

TLDR; You cannot detect this.

also, double freeing the same object is Undefined Behavior. It doesn't guarantee a crash. It might crash, it might be a noop, it might mess up another unrelated object.

That being said, in debug builds some compilers set "deleted memory" to 0xDDDDDDDD  and you might catch it during testing (but only if other parts of code don't start to reuse the memory immediately). But in release builds there is no way at all.

What does the legacy code do with the raw pointer exactly? An answer might depend on that. Does this legacy code have access to the class definition of the pointed object?

What does 3rd party library's doc mention about the matter? If there's no docs, the library is worthless. If the code doesn't behave as claimed, its a library bug. If the library deletes the object it didn't create, it's bad design; and if it deletes the object without any kind of feedback/notification to the caller, it's a true disaster. Otherwise if you are trying to push the library beyond it's defined territory and purposely force it to it's UB, there's no redemption for you.

I am not sure why a library would take it upon itself to delete a pointer that it, itself did not create. Do you have an actual example of a library that does this?

The more I thought about it, the more I took fright at the thought of throwing an exception from a destructor: it's so comprehensively frowned upon that I shouldn't wonder if it gets removed from C++ altogether in some future standard.
So partially following @bolov's suggestion, I used an assert:
class undeletable
{
public:
    undeletable() : safeToDelete(false) {}

protected:  // Prevents deletion from within the code
    virtual ~undeletable()
    {
        assert(safeToDelete);
    }

private:
    void setSafeToDelete { safeToDelete = true; }
    bool safeToDelete;

    friend class deleteTheUndeletable;
};


class deleteTheUndeletable
{
public:
     void operator()(undeletable * obj) const
     {
         obj->setSafeToDelete();
         delete obj;
     }
 };

Then, any attempt to delete an 'undeletable' by any means at all, even if it happens from the depths of a third-party library, except by explicitly calling:
deleteTheUndeletable(myObject);

... will cause an assert failure at runtime when running with DEBUG enabled, so that the location of the unintended deletion can easily be identified and fixed.

First of all, double freeing the same object is Undefined Behavior. It doesn't guarantee a crash. It might crash, it might be a noop, it might mess up some other unrelated object, it might do anything.
I agree with the comments in that you should not try to modify the code around this possible bug, but instead use tools like valgrind and such to detect such errors.
However if you really want to safeguard your code this way, I would go with std::abort instead of throwing. I would probably create a helper object DeleteLock which you can use to detect (by aborting the program) when such scenario occurs. Like so:
class DeleteLock
{
private:
    bool is_locked = false;

public:
    void Lock() { is_locked = true; }
    void Unlock() { is_locked = false; }

    ~DeleteLock()
    {
        if (is_locked == true)
        {
            std::abort();
        }
    }
};

// your class, just add the lock object, no other changes neeeded
struct X
{
    DeleteLock delete_lock{};

    /* rest of your class unchanged */
};

void legacy_foo(X* x)
{
    delete x;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<X> x = std::make_unique<X>();

    // call Lock and Unlock around passing the pointer to legacy code:

    x->delete_lock.Lock();
    legacy_foo(x.get());
    x->delete_lock.Unlock();
}


Thank you. Even so, I'm minded to stick with my original plan, but I'll put an IFDEF _DEBUG block around the scary stuff. The background to all of this is that my objects are Qt widgets, which under normal circumstances get 'parented' to another widget (ultimately the Main Window) and are deleted automatically when the parent goes out of scope. I want to prevent this, and archive the widgets separately for re-use within another parent. However, I don't want to miss any. 1/2

The scope of what I'm trying to do is strictly for development/debugging, and I mainly work in Visual Studio so I don't want to use Valgrind. Once I've intercepted all the unwanted automatic deletions, I'll have no further use for the detection mechanism, and I don't want it to be in the Release code anyway. I've tested it out and verified that, in the meantime, it does what I need it to do. 2/2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

as for the getting rid of it after the detection, I think my solution is more manageable. When you are ready you delete the DeleteLock class and then delete every use of it (you will find all of them easily because it will error at compilation at the exact use case site). In your version you will also might want  to change the unique_ptr types to a default deleter type. I am not saying my version is better as only you know your code base and use case , I am showing you the options you have with it.
